# Issue while installing instapy from pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-fn4sb8xi/grpcio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-fn4sb8xi/grpcio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-record-kxm3tsc2/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/python3.8/grpcio
         cwd: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-fn4sb8xi/grpcio/
    Complete output (411 lines):
    Found cython-generated files...
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_project_metadata
    creating python_build
    creating python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8
    creating python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_auth.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_channel.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_common.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_compression.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_grpcio_metadata.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_interceptor.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_plugin_wrapping.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_server.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_simple_stubs.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_utilities.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc
    creating python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/_cython
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/_cython
    creating python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/beta
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/beta/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/beta
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/beta
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/beta/_metadata.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/beta
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/beta/_server_adaptations.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/beta
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/beta/implementations.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/beta
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/beta/interfaces.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/beta
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/beta/utilities.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/beta
    creating python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/experimental
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/experimental/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/experimental
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/experimental/gevent.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/experimental
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/experimental/session_cache.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/experimental
    creating python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework
    creating python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc
    creating python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/experimental/aio
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/experimental/aio/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/experimental/aio
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/experimental/aio/_base_call.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/experimental/aio
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/experimental/aio/_base_channel.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/experimental/aio
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/experimental/aio/_base_server.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/experimental/aio
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/experimental/aio/_call.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/experimental/aio
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/experimental/aio/_channel.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/experimental/aio
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/experimental/aio/_interceptor.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/experimental/aio
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/experimental/aio/_metadata.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/experimental/aio
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/experimental/aio/_server.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/experimental/aio
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/experimental/aio/_typing.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/experimental/aio
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/experimental/aio/_utils.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/experimental/aio
    creating python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/common
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/common/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/common
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/common/cardinality.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/common
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/common/style.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/common
    creating python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/foundation
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/foundation/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/foundation
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/foundation/abandonment.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/foundation
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/foundation/callable_util.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/foundation
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/foundation/future.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/foundation
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/foundation/logging_pool.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/foundation
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/foundation/stream.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/foundation
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/foundation/stream_util.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/foundation
    creating python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/interfaces
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/interfaces/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/interfaces
    creating python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/interfaces/base
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/interfaces/base/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/interfaces/base
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/interfaces/base/base.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/interfaces/base
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/interfaces/base/utilities.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/interfaces/base
    creating python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/interfaces/face
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/interfaces/face/__init__.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/interfaces/face
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/interfaces/face/face.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/interfaces/face
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/framework/interfaces/face/utilities.py -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/framework/interfaces/face
    creating python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/_cython/_credentials
    copying src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_credentials/roots.pem -> python_build/lib.linux-armv8l-3.8/grpc/_cython/_credentials
    running build_ext
    Found cython-generated files...
    building 'grpc._cython.cygrpc' extension
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/python
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/python/grpcio
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/python/grpcio/grpc
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/census
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/health
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/priority
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/round_robin
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/weighted_target
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/xds
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/native
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/fake
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/sockaddr
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/xds
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/xds
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/client_idle
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/deadline
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/http
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/http/client
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/http/message_compress
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/http/server
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/max_age
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/message_size
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/filters/workarounds
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/transport
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/alpn
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/client
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/client/insecure
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/client/secure
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/insecure
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/secure
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/transport/inproc
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/annotations
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/api
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/api/v2
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/api/v2/auth
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/api/v2/cluster
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/api/v2/core
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/api/v2/endpoint
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/api/v2/listener
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/api/v2/route
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/filter
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/filter/accesslog
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/filter/accesslog/v2
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/filter/network
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/filter/network/http_connection_manager
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/filter/network/http_connection_manager/v2
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/listener
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/listener/v2
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/trace
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/trace/v2
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/service
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/service/discovery
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/service/discovery/v2
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/service/load_stats
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/service/load_stats/v2
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/type
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/type/matcher
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/type/metadata
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/type/metadata/v2
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/type/tracing
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/type/tracing/v2
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/gogoproto
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/google
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/google/api
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/google/protobuf
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/google/rpc
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/src
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/src/proto
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/src/proto/grpc
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/src/proto/grpc/gcp
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/src/proto/grpc/health
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/src/proto/grpc/health/v1
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/src/proto/grpc/lb
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/src/proto/grpc/lb/v1
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/udpa
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/udpa/annotations
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/udpa/data
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/udpa/data/orca
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/udpa/data/orca/v1
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/ext/upb-generated/validate
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/avl
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/backoff
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/channel
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/compression
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/debug
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/gpr
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/gprpp
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/http
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/iomgr
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/iomgr/executor
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/iomgr/poller
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/json
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/profiling
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security/context
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security/credentials
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security/credentials/alts
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security/credentials/composite
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security/credentials/fake
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security/credentials/google_default
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security/credentials/iam
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security/credentials/jwt
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security/credentials/local
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security/credentials/oauth2
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security/credentials/plugin
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security/credentials/ssl
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security/credentials/tls
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security/security_connector
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security/security_connector/alts
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security/security_connector/fake
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security/security_connector/local
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security/security_connector/ssl
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security/security_connector/tls
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security/transport
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/security/util
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/core/lib/slice
.
.
.
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/bio
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/bn_extra
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/buf
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/bytestring
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/chacha
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/cipher_extra
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/cmac
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/conf
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/curve25519
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/dh
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/digest_extra
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/dsa
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/ec_extra
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/ecdh_extra
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/ecdsa_extra
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/engine
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/err
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/evp
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/fipsmodule
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/hkdf
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/hrss
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/lhash
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/obj
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/pem
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/pkcs7
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/pkcs8
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/poly1305
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/pool
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/rand_extra
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/rc4
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/rsa_extra
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/siphash
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/stack
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/trust_token
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/x509
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/crypto/x509v3
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/ssl
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/cares
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/cares/cares
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/upb
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/upb/upb
    creating python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/third_party/zlib
    arm-linux-androideabi-clang -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -fPIC -DOPENSSL_NO_ASM=1 -D_WIN32_WINNT=1536 -DGPR_BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY_MODE=1 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H=1 -DGRPC_ENABLE_FORK_SUPPORT=1 -DPyMODINIT_FUNC=extern "C" __attribute__((visibility ("default"))) PyObject* -DGRPC_POSIX_FORK_ALLOW_PTHREAD_ATFORK=1 -Isrc/python/grpcio -Iinclude -I. -Ithird_party/abseil-cpp -Ithird_party/address_sorting/include -Ithird_party/cares -Ithird_party/cares/cares -Ithird_party/cares/config_linux -Ithird_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/include -Ithird_party/upb -Isrc/core/ext/upb-generated -Ithird_party/zlib -I/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/python3.8 -c src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpp -o python_build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.8/src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.o -std=c++11 -std=gnu99 -fvisibility=hidden -fno-wrapv -fno-exceptions -pthread
    error: invalid argument '-std=gnu99' not allowed with 'C++'
    creating data
    creating data/data
    creating data/data/com.termux
    creating data/data/com.termux/files
    creating data/data/com.termux/files/usr
    creating data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp
    creating data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmpn4iv295l
    arm-linux-androideabi-clang -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -fPIC -I/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/python3.8 -c /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmpn4iv295l/a.c -o data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmpn4iv295l/a.o
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 117, in _compile
        self.spawn(compiler_so + cc_args + [src, '-o', obj] +
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-fn4sb8xi/grpcio/src/python/grpcio/_spawn_patch.py", line 54, in _commandfile_spawn
        _classic_spawn(self, command)
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 910, in spawn
        spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/spawn.py", line 36, in spawn
        _spawn_posix(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/spawn.py", line 157, in _spawn_posix
        raise DistutilsExecError(
    distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'arm-linux-androideabi-clang' failed with exit status 1

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-fn4sb8xi/grpcio/src/python/grpcio/commands.py", line 262
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using python if you cannot install an package with the help of pip u can install it manually:- 1. Install package zip from the package distributor website
2. Unzip it
3. Move it to :-
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages
This is the app data of python.... The above path is the path were all the python modules are stored. Not only in python in any language if you have to install any package you can manually install it and move it to appdata of the particular language.

Comment: Can i do that with wget